# CRM 2011: Global JavaScript and button in status bar

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm not so new in CRM 2011, but I faced with one big problem... I found some solution on net that makes some scoring/ranking system in CRM. I was completely confused when I saw star in top status bar, above ribbon buttons bar, next to username on right corner of screen.

[image]

When I click on this button, I open div with some information about users, and scores they have.

1. Where I can put Java Script function (jQuery for example) that can be executed globally? How to call that function, what event to catch? I need this button/function be active on all pages in CRM like this one.
2. What is id of that place in top bar? I need it to put this button from my script.

Comment: Can you post a link? Sounds like an unsupport customisation

Comment: Are you asking for help using a solution you have downloaded and installed, or help in reproducing something similar to an example you have seen? (in which case how about linking to the actual example web page?)

Comment: I need to make something similar to this. @James Wood: I think I get it from store, not sure ;-)

Comment: Looks unsupported to me.

Comment: Why don't you create an application ribbon button that would show up in all homepage/grid/subgrid areas? This could call a custom webresource that shows the user information you want.

Comment: It appears this is the solution in question. http://www.wave-access.com/Public_en/ms_crm_gamification_product.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CRM solution you appear to be talking about is this

http://www.wave-access.com/Public_en/ms_crm_gamification_product.aspx

This is obviously unsupported.
However they achieve it by adding a dummy button to the ribbon, specifically the Jewel Menu.
This button command is linked to a JS function in a webresource.
The button is always hidden but the JS file is always loaded.

It should be noted that your JS is loaded into Main.aspx (the root document)
From there its a matter of injecting HTML elements or javascript into the desired frame. (Nav or Content)

Here is the RibbonDiffXML to add to a solution.

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
<CustomActions>
  <CustomAction Id="Dummy.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Jewel.Controls1._children" Sequence="41">
    <CommandUIDefinition>
      <Button Id="Dummy" Command="Dummy.Command" Sequence="50" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:Dummy.LabelText" LabelText="$LocLabels:Dummy.LabelText" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:Dummy.Description" TemplateAlias="isv" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CustomAction>
</CustomActions>
<Templates>
  <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
</Templates>
<CommandDefinitions>
  <CommandDefinition Id="Dummy.Command">
    <EnableRules />
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Dummy.Command.DisplayRule.PageRule" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
      <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:MyGlobal.js" FunctionName="Anything" />
    </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
</CommandDefinitions>
<RuleDefinitions>
  <TabDisplayRules />
  <DisplayRules>
    <DisplayRule Id="Dummy.Command.DisplayRule.PageRule">
      <PageRule Address="aaaa" />
    </DisplayRule>
  </DisplayRules>
  <EnableRules />
</RuleDefinitions>
<LocLabels>
  <LocLabel Id="Dummy.Description">
    <Titles>
      <Title languagecode="1033" description="Description" />
    </Titles>
  </LocLabel>
  <LocLabel Id="Dummy.LabelText">
    <Titles>
      <Title languagecode="1033" description="Description" />
    </Titles>
  </LocLabel>
</LocLabels>
```

This goes in the root ImportExportXml element of the customizations.xml
You may also need to add Application Ribbons as a solution component via the UI

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion but for me it is not working, the Javascript file is not loaded when the button is hidden. I had to add the button to the SubGrid/Grid/Dashboard section, but that still leave me the Settings area. And I want to hide the button as well. Do you have any more idea?

Comment: The Jewel menu is not available anymore in MS CRM 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309420.aspx However according to the website that CRM Gamification Tool is available for MS CRM 2013 as well. Do you know how they still placing button there?