# CRM 2013: Global JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to have JavaScript file globally available in MS CRM 2013 installation. I need to use it's functions on every single page / frame. To achieve this I'm ready to go with any unsupported customization (except cases not available in MS CRM Online).

Do you any idea what working approaches could be?

I have found [one article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796821/crm-2011-global-javascript-and-button-in-status-bar), however it is based on MS CRM 2011 and don't work in version 2013.

Many thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: So you have to be able to do it in CRM Online?  Is that what you mean by except cases not available in MS CRM Online?

Comment: I mean server-side customizations — editing `main.aspx`, for example, that I actually cannot implement on CRM Online. I need solution to be available for all CRM installation types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the source code of this navigation solution:

https://crm2013oneclicknavigation.codeplex.com/

It injects a JavaScript called by the application ribbon making it available everywhere and works with CRM 2013 (also Online).

Comment: Thank you, it looks like what I was searching for!